# Adjusting the column height of a Word 2007 Mail Merge on every page?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, mail-merge, label

I've been doing mail merges lately and we use labels that aren't listed in the default MS Word settings:

[image: Universal UNV-80120 labels box]

I tried measuring them out and here is what I got:

[image: Universal UNV-80120 labels measurements (by me and my ruler)]

Despite measuring them they don't seem to fit, and I always end up having to adjust the heights so that they print correctly.  When I do this and I have 24 pages or so of labels I have to adjust each page individually and it all gets a bit annoying.

So I was wondering if anyone had the proper measurements (since mine didn't work) or if maybe someone knew how to adjust the height of the columns of every page in exactly the same way to avoid using more labels.

Comment: Nevermind I used a macro...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that as below should be close enough:

[image: SU515459 example]

and that it might be a printer issue (whose make/model we do not know) for lack of sufficient selvage for handling the paper.

I recall some irritation when setting up label printing but that was a 'one off' and has served me well for about 18 years since.

However, at least when I was getting frustrated the pages were behaving consistently! If you are needing to adjust page by page it sounds as though your printer may be expecting A4 when actually being fed Letter.